# Cloudera sandbox 2.6.5 does not save settings

Tags: hadoop

I connected to the sandbox (2.6.5) using putty and upgraded the sqlite version from 3.7 to 3.37.

But after the connection is cut off, it's reset to 3.7.

What should I do if I want to keep the version at 3.37.

Or,
I'm going to configure an airflow in this sandbox.
But there was a problem because of the sqlite version. Can you give me another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, the HDP/Cloudera Sandbox use Docker. No, Docker is not persistent.

If you want to use Airflow, then you can easily set that up yourself in Docker. You don't necessarily need a Hadoop environment for that.